# How to see changes inside Paragraphs or Field Collections with Diff

Tags: 7, entities, paragraphs

I have read and checked that [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) and [Field Collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) revisions are tracked. But when I make a change to the node and then look at the Revisions tab, no changes done with fields inside Paragraphs or FC are displayed. Does Diff support display of those changes? If yes, how can I see them?

Things I checked:

1. Enable the Revisions page for this content type is checked.
2. Standard comparison preview is Full Content and it has paragraphs field displayed.
3. Diff module is installed and enabled.
4. On page admin/config/content/diff/fields in Global settings for Paragraphs Markdown callback is set to "Drupal HTML to text", as well as for those field types that are inside paragraph.

I can see field changes for my content type, but the comparison page does not show changes for fields that are inside paragraph. 
What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install and enable the [Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module.

> This module adds a tab for sufficiently permissioned users. The tab
>   shows all revisions like standard Drupal but it also allows pretty
>   viewing of all added/changed/deleted words between revisions.

Nothing else is needed.

Given a simple paragraph with a boolean field and a text field, if oyu change the textfield uou will get someting like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have Diff installed and enabled. I see changes made to other fields of my content type, but not fields that are inside paragraph that is part of that same content type.

Comment: That setup is the same as mine in the screenshot. I've done using simplytest.me, so it was a fresh Drupal with Paragraph and Diff installed and enabled. May be there's a module or settings interfering. Have you checked dblog and PHP errors and warnings?